# Задача на обход таблицы в Python

Tags: python

Задание звучит так: Каково наибольшее произведение четырех подряд идущих чисел в таблице 20×20, расположенных в любом направлении (вверх, вниз, вправо, влево или по диагонали)? (сама таблица в коде)

Моё решение:

```
s = '08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 \
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 \
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 \
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 \
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 \
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 \
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 \
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 \
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 \
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 \
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 \
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 \
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 \
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 \
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 \
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 \
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 \
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 \
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 \
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'
mas = []
sp = s.split(' ')
k = 0

for i in range(20):
    ltek = []
    for j in range(20):
        ltek.append(int(sp[k]))
        k += 1
    mas.append(ltek)

max = 0
for i in range(17):
    for j in range(17):

        x = mas[i][j] * mas[i][j + 1] * mas[i][j + 2] * mas[i][j + 3]
        if x > max: max = x

        x = mas[i][j] * mas[i + 1][j] * mas[i + 2][j] * mas[i + 3][j]
        if x > max: max = x

        x = mas[i][j] * mas[i + 1][j + 1] * mas[i + 2][j + 2] * mas[i + 3][j + 3]
        if x > max: max = x

print(max)
```

Ответ выводит неверный, не могу понять, что я успускаю?

Comment: почему только до 17? У вас уже в этом ошибка

Comment: @Эникейщик извиняюсь, маленько не так подумал

Comment: @Эникейщик при подсчете правый нижний угол никак не проверятся.

Comment: @danilshik да, точно. Горизонтально на нижних строчках и вертикально в правых столбцах не проверяется. (это задача из проекта Эйлера).

Comment: @Эникейщик и по диагонали в некоторых случаях

Answer (score 0):

Диагоналей две. Так / ↗️и так \ ↘️, а в коде считается только так - \ ↘️

Comment: Спасибо, учёл, теперь ответ верный

Answer (score 0):

У меня как то вот так получилось :D

```
s = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 \
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 \
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 \
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 \
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 \
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 \
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 \
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 \
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 \
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 \
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 \
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 \
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 \
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 \
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 \
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 \
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 \
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 \
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 \
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"
sp = s.split(" ")

def filling_mas():
    mas = []
    k = 0

    for x in range(20):
        lst = []

        for y in range(20):
            lst.append(int(sp[k]))
            k += 1

        mas.append(lst)

    return mas

def main():
    mas = filling_mas()
    maximum = 0

    for x in range(17):
        for y in range(17):

            # по діагоналі вправо вниз

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x + 1][y + 1] * mas[x + 2][y + 2] * mas[x + 3][x + 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

            # по діагоналі вправо вверх

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x - 1][y + 1] * mas[x - 2][y + 2] * mas[x - 3][x + 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

            # по вертикалі вниз

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x + 1][y] * mas[x + 2][y] * mas[x + 3][y]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

            # по вертикалі вверх

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x - 1][y] * mas[x - 2][y] * mas[x - 3][y]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

            # по горизонталі вправо

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x][y + 1] * mas[x][y + 2] * mas[x][y + 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

            # по діагоналі вліво вниз

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x + 1][y - 1] * mas[x + 2][y - 2] * mas[x + 3][y - 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

    for x in range(3, 20):
        for y in range(3, 20):

            # по діагоналі вліво вверх

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x - 1][y - 1] * mas[x - 2][y - 2] * mas[x - 3][y - 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

    for x in range(20):
        for y in range(3, 20):

            # по горизонталі вліво

            num = mas[x][y] * mas[x][y - 1] * mas[x][y - 2] * mas[x][y - 3]
            if num > maximum:
                maximum = num

    return maximum

print(main())
```

Comment: можно значительно сократить количество кода.